# YouTube, music copyright and monetizing

Tags: youtube, copyright

I have some popular YouTube videos, where I've used songs that I don't have the legal right to use. This of course has disabled the monetizing for some of my videos, which doesn't really bother me. I don't have to earn money from my videos.

What I feel is odd that when I look at the copyright claim, YouTube says that the copyright owner is able to turn on advertising on my videos. Does this mean that both me and the owner of the music split the money, or does everything go to the owner of the music?

Answer (score 1):

You don't share it. All the generated advertising revenue [goes to the copyright owner/claimant](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6013276?hl=en).

> Depending on the copyright owner’s policy, some Content ID claims prevent certain material from being available on YouTube. Others allow the video to remain live, while directing the advertising revenue to the copyright owners of the claimed content, like music.

Comment: Why do they do it like this? I mean, how can they claim copyright for the entire video, when all the visual aspects of the video still is my original content? Of course if the video is uploaded with the main purpose of only sharing the song, I could understand this. But when I use my own video material, I don't really see why the copyright owners of the song takes all the revenue. I understand that music labels wants to earn their money as well, but to be honest, I don't think the way YouTube deals with this is a good way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't make sense for those who use other people's music, but it's probably where YouTube made a concession to allow them to keep going. They do have a few help articles that mention a few times that you should only upload where you own the content entirely, or have permission to use, so that would be them trying to let users know what's in their best interests too